# Rounded corners for Safari/Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, rounded-corners

So I've tried everything that everyone's recommended to fix this problem which is why I'm reaching out for help. I've got a rounded corners problem, it's displaying the way it should on Firefox but not Safari or Chrome. Here's my code:

```
#sidebar4_content{
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: right;
    width:80%;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    margin-top: 130px;
    height: 600px;
    border: solid 5px #1C1C1C;
    border-top-left-radius:90%;/*Opera 10.5, IE 9*/
    border-bottom-left-radius:90%;/*Opera 10.5, IE 9*/
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 90%; /*Disabled for FF1+*/
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 90%;/*Disabled for FF1+*/
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 90%;/* Saf3+, Chrome*/
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 90%;/* Saf3+, Chrome*/
}
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations such as working with "px" as opposed to "%," getting everything in this sort of format: border-radius: 0px 90px 90px 0px; and the comments are something I also tried because somebody out there recommended it but nothing's working. 
What's strange is that the corners are rounded in Safari and Chrome but at 10px and all four sides even when I have the sides specified. 
Help please!

Comment: can you reproduce it in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code seems to work for me in Chrome when I paste it verbatim into jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/VTgAn/

and when I look at inspect element in Chrome, it is using these rules as expected:

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 90%;/* Saf3+, Chrome*/
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 90%;/* Saf3+, Chrome*/
```

Is it possible that you have some other css that is causing conflicts? What does it look like when you do inspect element?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure nothing is in conflict with your CSS?
For me when i fiddle this css in both FF and Chrome it comes out exactly the same.
( [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3yq8/) )

Try forcing them with a !important tag to see if it works, if it does, something is overruling your css you showed here, and you should look into chrome's devmode to see wich one is the over-ruling one.

so:

```
#sidebar4_content{
margin: 0 auto;
float: right;
width:80%;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
margin-top: 130px;
height: 600px;
border: solid 5px #1C1C1C;
border-top-left-radius:90% !important;/*Opera 10.5, IE 9*/
border-bottom-left-radius:90% !important;/*Opera 10.5, IE 9*/
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 90% !important; /*Disabled for FF1+*/
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 90% !important;/*Disabled for FF1+*/
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 90% !important;/* Saf3+, Chrome*/
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 90% !important;/* Saf3+, Chrome*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Kevin! You're right, it does work! I inspected the element and realized that my Fetch had shut down so it wasn't making live edits... That's embarrassing! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Good to hear that you found the troublemaker! And am glad i could be of assistance. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me on chrome and safari. Maybe try setting the other 2 corners to 0.

```
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;/* Saf3+, Chrome*/
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;/* Saf3+, Chrome*/
```